# Issue with dynamically changing the app icon on app close (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my app terminates, I want it to change the app icon back to the default icon. For this, I implemented this code:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([application supportsAlternateIcons] == NO)
            return;

    [application setAlternateIconName:@"alternate"
                                          completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                              NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
                                          }];
}
```

This does not seem to work, and I don't understand why. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? is applicationWillTerminate called? Does the completion return? If so, does it have an error (which one, if so)?

Answer (score 0):

Once you return from `applicationWillTerminate`, the system will end your process, so `setAlternateIconName` might not have time to finish.

You have about 5 seconds to return from this function, so I recommend that you use a semaphore to wait for it.

Something like:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([application supportsAlternateIcons] == NO)
            return;

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);


    [application setAlternateIconName:@"alternate"
                                          completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                              NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
                                              dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                                          }];

     // Wait 3 seconds -- we have ~5 seconds to return
     dispatch_time_t waitTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

     dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, waitTime);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortuantely that doesn't seem to work either. I tried your suggeestion with ```applicationWillEnterForeground```, and that did not work either. I'm a little lost honestly.

```applicationWillTerminate``` is called and there doesn't seem to be an error.

Comment: is the completion called?